# MySQL Rolling Subtraction of a given qantity

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `PQ_batch` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Batch Id number',
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `qty` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Number of units in a batch',
  PRIMARY KEY (`bid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1000 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


Id    |    date       | qty
--------------------------------
1        2017-01-06     5
2        2017-01-02     5
3        2017-01-03     100
```

*Given a qty value of*: **@qtyToTake:=100**

***Select the rows that will be needed to fulfill the @qtyToTake and ONLY these rows, the quantity that is to be taken from each row, and the new quantity that remains for that row.  The oldest batches should be used up first. ***

It should look something like this:

```
Id    |    date       | qty  |  newQty   | qtyTakenPerRecord
-------------------------------------------------------
1        2017-01-02     5       0           5 
2        2017-01-03     100     5           95 
3        2017-01-01     5       5           0
```

newQty = (qty - @qtyToTake) where @qtyToTake = (@qtyToTake - the previous row's qty until @qtyToTake reaches 0)

@qtyToTake should be dynamically assigned to be the difference of the previous row's qty and its current value until it reaches 0.

Here's what I came up with:

```
SELECT p.bid, p.Orig as origQty, p.NewQty, (p.Orig - p.NewQty) AS NumToTake 
        FROM( 
            SELECT  b.bid, (@runtot :=  b.bqty  - @runtot) AS remain, ( @runtot := (b.bqty - @runtot) ) leftToGet, b.bqty AS Orig,
             (SELECT
                 (sum(bqty) - @runtot) AS tot  FROM PQ_batch
               WHERE bid <= b.bid )  AS RunningTotal, 
               (SELECT
                  CASE  
                       WHEN (sum(bqty) - @runtot) > 1 THEN (sum(bqty) - @runtot)
                       ELSE 0
                   END
                    FROM PQ_batch
                    WHERE bid <= b.bid )   AS NewQty
            FROM    PQ_batch b,(SELECT @runtot:= 100) c
            ORDER BY bdate
         ) AS p
```

Comment: Please, this has no sense, try to improve your explanation.

Comment: How are you determining the `newQty` column?

Comment: No (visible) effort on trying to solve the problem, unclear question...

Comment: @McNets I've updated the question,  I hope that helps clarify.

Comment: @Alfabravo I've included my attempt to provide a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using @McNets example here's what I came up with:

```
SELECT bid, bdate,bpid,bcost, bqty, newQty, qtyTakenPerRecord
        FROM (
                SELECT y.*,
                       IF(@qtyToTake > 0, 1, 0) AS used,
                       IF(@qtyToTake > bqty, 0, bqty - @qtyToTake) AS newQty,
                       IF(@qtyToTake > bqty, bqty, bqty - (bqty - @qtyToTake)) AS qtyTakenPerRecord,
                       @qtyToTake := @qtyToTake - bqty AS qtyToTake
                FROM
                    (SELECT @qtyToTake := 100) x,
                    (SELECT * from PQ_batch  WHERE bpid =1002 AND bqty > 0 ORDER BY bdate) y
             ) z
        WHERE used = 1
        ORDER BY bdate
```